# How to hide some table columns based on screen size while using repeat Angular Material

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-material

I have a table that contains multiple columns and rows. When viewing on a small screen(phone) i want to hide some of those columns, otherwise show all columns.
The data inside my table is populated using a repeat. As i re-use the table in multiple places i would like to keep the repeat as the column and row count is different.

```
<table md-table class="md-data-table" id="data-table">
            <thead md-head md-order="gridCtrl.gridModel.orderBy">
            <tr md-row>
                <th md-column ng-repeat="header in gridCtrl.gridModel.headers" md-order-by="fields[{{$index}}].value">
                    {{header.title}}
                </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody md-body>
            <tr md-row ng-repeat="item in gridCtrl.gridModel.items | orderBy: gridCtrl.gridModel.orderBy | limitTo: gridCtrl.gridModel.itemsPerPage : (gridCtrl.gridModel.firstPage -1) * gridCtrl.gridModel.itemsPerPage">
                <td md-cell ng-repeat="field in item.fields">
                    <div ng-if="gridCtrl.isLink(field)">
                        <h4 class="blue-link" id="gridFieldString{{field.value | idfy}}" ng-click="gridCtrl.click($event, field)">
                            {{field.value}}
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                    <div ng-if="!gridCtrl.isLink(field)">{{field.value}}</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: Read up about material design (which you seem to be using): https://material.io/guidelines/layout/responsive-ui.html#responsive-ui-breakpoints

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
window.screen.availHeight
window.screen.availWidth
```

to get the current resolution.

Then add a ng-hide with screen resolution or

```
<tr md-row ng-hide="window.screen.availHeight < 500 && window.screen.availWidth <200">
```

Comment: This will hide all the rows, i can do the same by adding hide-xs or hide-sm for example. My question is how to hide only some columns from the repeats

Answer (score 0):

You need to read media queries and define rules according to screen width

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp